# Save ggplot in loop with R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a dataset with numeric and factor variables. I want to do one page with numeric and other with factor var. First of all, i select factor var with his index.

My df is IRIS dataset.

```
df<-iris
df$y<-sample(0:1,nrow(iris),replace=TRUE)
fact<-colnames(df)[sapply(df,is.factor)]
index_fact<-which(names(df)%in%fact)
```

Then i calculate rest of it (numerics)

```
nm<-ncol(df)-length(fact)
```

Next step is create loop

```
i_F=1
i_N=1
list_plotN<- list()
list_plotF<- list()

for (i in 1:length(df)){
  plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=df[,i],color=y,fill=y))+xlab(names(df)[i]) 

  if (is.factor(df[,i])){
    p_factor<-plot+geom_bar()
    list_plotF[[i_F]]<-p_factor
    i_F=i_F+1
  }else{
    p_numeric <- plot+geom_histogram()
    list_plotN[[i_N]]<-p_numeric
    i_N=i_N+1
  }
}
```

When i see list_plotF and list_plot_N,it didn't well. It always have same vars. i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

thanks!!!

Comment: I cannot see any value for `y` in your example

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50383146/786542

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing column names with `aes_string` to better align *x* with *df*:

```
for (i in 1:length(df)){
    plot <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=names(df)[i], color="y", fill="y")) + 
              xlab(names(df)[i]) 
    ...
}
```

---

To demonstrate the problem using `aes()` and solution using `aes_string()` in OP's context, consider the following random data frame with columns of different data types: factor, char, int, num, bool, date.

**Data**

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1152019)
alpha <- c(LETTERS, letters, c(0:9))
data_tools <- c("sas", "stata", "spss", "python", "r", "julia")

random_df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(data_tools, 500, replace=TRUE),
  int = as.numeric(sample(1:15, 500, replace=TRUE)),
  num = rnorm(500),
  char = replicate(500, paste(sample(LETTERS[1:2], 3, replace=TRUE), collapse="")),
  bool = as.numeric(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 500, replace=TRUE)),
  date = as.Date(sample(as.integer(as.Date('2019-01-01', origin='1970-01-01')):as.integer(Sys.Date()), 
                        500, replace=TRUE), origin='1970-01-01')
)
```

**Graph**

```
fact <- colnames(random_df)[sapply(random_df,is.factor)]
index_fact <- which(names(random_df) %in% fact)

i_F=1
i_N=1
list_plotN <- list()
list_plotF <- list()
plot <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(random_df)){
  # aes() VERSION
  #plot <- ggplot(random_df, aes(x=random_df[,i], color=group, fill=group)) +
  #  xlab(names(random_df)[i]) 

  # aes_string() VERSION
  plot <- ggplot(random_df, aes_string(x=names(random_df)[i], color="group", fill="group")) +
    xlab(names(random_df)[i]) 

  if (is.factor(random_df[,i])){
    p_factor <- plot + geom_bar()
    list_plotF[[i_F]] <- p_factor
    i_F=i_F+1
  }else{
    p_numeric <- plot + geom_histogram()
    list_plotN[[i_N]] <- p_numeric
    i_N=i_N+1
  }
}
```

---

**Problem** *(using `aes()` where graph outputs DO NOT change according to type)*

[image: Problem Plots]

---

**Solution** *(using `aes_string()` where graphs DO change according to type)*

[image: Solution Plots]

Comment: Really? What error do you get? Works great on my end.

Comment: Come to think of it, your problem is unclear. *It always have same vars.* ... what does this mean? Without `aes_string`, the x-axis does not change between plots which I assumed is your *same vars* issue.

Comment: If you see list_plotF (expected graphs for factor vars) and list_plotN (expected graphs numerical vars), you could check both list are same.  even plot is a list with all plots.

Comment: I edited showing the differences in using `aes()` and `aes_string()` in your context. I believe `iris` may not be a good example since all columns except *species* are numeric. See my random data (seeded for reproducibility) of columns of all types: char, num, int, bool, and date. See the problem and solution outputs.

Comment: What IDE are you using? RStudio? RGui? Rscript at command line? How are you viewing the plots?

Comment: but i don't know why p_numeric  p_factor  and plot objects are list with all graphs. is there one way to do it efficiently?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by *all graphs*. RStudio's plot window shows *all* graphs *ever* called in a session from console or script. You might be confusing which is which. Try individually running: `list_plotF[[1]]`, `list_plotF[[2]]`, ...

Comment: yes but if you see p_factor  is not empty true? how many graphs are in this object? @parfait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186807/discussion-between-liguang-and-parfait).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow your for loop code all that well. But from what I see it seems to be saving the last plot in every loop you make. I've reconstructed what I think you need using lapply. I generally prefer lapply to for loops whenever I can.

Lapply takes a list of values and a function and applies that function to every value. you can define your function separately like I have so everything looks cleaner. Then you just mention the function in the lapply command.

In our case the list is a list of columns from your dataframe `df`. The function it applies first creates our base plot. Then it does a quick check to see if the column it is looking at is a factor.. If it's a factor it creates a bar graph, else it creates a histogram.

```
histOrBar <- function(var) {
  basePlot <- ggplot(df, aes_string(var))
  if ( is.factor(df[[var]]) ) {
    basePlot + geom_bar()  
  } else {
    basePlot + geom_histogram()
  }
}

loDFs <- lapply(colnames(df), histOrBar)
```

Comment: is there possible to pass df like argument of apply? @Sahir Moosvi

Comment: There is a set of apply functions. the base apply function can take a dataframe.